# Angularjs Cannot read property 'id' of undefined

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I am new to angularjs, I'm trying to create a webapp that can access data from server and post the data to the server. But I'm facing issues, what I did in my application, I have created module,service,view and controller in separate files. I'm unable to access and post data to the server. Can anyone help me.

> home.js(controller file)

```
var myapp = angular.module('demo').controller("homeController",          function($scope,myService){
var userArray = {
   Id:$scope.user.id,
   Model:$scope.user.model,
   Name:$scope.user.name,
   Color:$scope.user.color,
   Price: $scope.user.price
};

myService.async().then(function(d){
  $scope.hello=d;
});

$scope.push = function(userArray){
  myService.saveUser(userArray).then(function(response){
  console.log("inserted");
   });
  }
});
```

> userService.js(service file)

```
myapp.factory('myService',function($http){
var myService={
async : function(){
  var promise=    $http.get('http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/1').then(function(response){
    console.log(response);
    return response;
  });
  return promise;
},
saveUser : function(user){
 $http.post('http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts',user).success(
   function(response,status,headers,config){
      });

     }
    };
  return myService;
 });
```

> restComponent.js(module file)

```
var myapp=angular
            .module('demo',['ui.router'])
            .config(function ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider){
              $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/home');
              $stateProvider
              .state('home',{
                url:'/home',
                templateUrl:'Templates/home.html',
                controller:'homeController'
              })
              .state('about', {
                url:'/about',
                templateUrl:'Templates/about.html',
                controller:'aboutController'
              })
              .state('contact',{
                url:'/contact',
                templateUrl:'Templates/contact.html',
                controller:'contactController'
              });

            });
```

> home.html (view file)

```
  <form ng-submit="mod.push();" ng-controller="homeController as mod">
    Id:<br>
    <input type="text" name="id" ng-model="mod.user.id"><br>
    Model:<br>
    <input type="text" name="model" ng-model="mod.user.model"><br>
    Name:<br>
    <input type="text" name="name" ng-model="mod.user.name"><br>
    Color:<br>
    <input type="text" name="color" ng-model="mod.user.color"><br>
    Price:<br>
    <input type="text" name="price" ng-model="mod.user.price"><br>
    <br>
    <input type="submit" >
  </form>

  <br>
  <br>


  <table>
    <thead>
      <th>UserId</th>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Country</th>

    </thead>
 <tbody>
   <tr ng-repeat="employee in hello">
   <td>{{employee.userId}}</td>
   <td>{{employee.name}}</td>
   <td>{{employee.country}}</td>
  </tr>
 </tbody>
 </table>
```

> index.html

```
 <!doctype html>
 <html lang="en" >
   <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <title>RestApi</title>
      <link rel="stylesheet"   href="bower_components/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css" />

       <script src="bower_components/angular/angular.js"></script>
       <script src="
       https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-  router/0.3.1/angular-ui-router.js
        "></script>
       <script src="rest-controller.component.js"></script>
       <script src="Controllers/contact.js"></script>
       <script src="Controllers/about.js"></script>
       <script src="Controllers/home.js"></script>
       <script src="Service/userService.js"></script>

    </head>
    <body ng-app="demo" >
     <ol>
       <li><a ui-sref="home">Home</a></li>
       <li><a ui-sref="about">About</a></li>
       <li><a ui-sref="contact">Contact</a></li>
    </ol>


    <div ui-view></div>
  </body>
 </html>
```

Comment: Can you update your question by adding console log?

Comment: what is the scope user? its undefined
you need to declare it somewhere before you use it
so your scope.user is undefined

Comment: you are mixing syntax here.  your controller is defined using `$scope` syntax but you are using `Controller as` syntax in your HTML.  also, don't use `controller` on your state and `ng-controller` in your HTML at the same time, use one or the other.

Comment: @claies then how do I get the data from view to controller.

Comment: which syntax do you *want* to use?  `$scope` and `Controller as` are totally different.

Comment: @Erez:  tel me where to declare the scope.user

Comment: @claies: I want to use $scope.

Comment: remove `ng-controller="homeController as mod"` from your view file (you don't need it, you already have a `controller` in your state.  then remove all the `mod.` from your bindings.

Comment: @claies: I removed  ng-controller="homeController as mod",  but still post is not working and get is calling two times

Comment: Please provide a plunkr or something with your code.

Answer (score 0):

change that

you didnt declare your scope so its undefined that why better to declare it before using it
also removes that user array you did not need for that

```
var myapp = angular.module('demo').controller("homeController",          function($scope,myService){
$scope.user = {}; // here you declare the user obkect
$scope.push = function(user){
    myService.saveUser(user).then(function(response){
      console.log("inserted");
    });
  }
})
```

and home html
  you wanted to use scope but you used controller var
the view know the scope and all his objects so just write the var fun name and it will go to it directly
or you can do the same with controller by using this instead of scope and mod like you did

here you should send the user or you can do it in controller by sending the `$scope.user`

```
<form ng-submit="push(user);">
    Id:<br>
    <input type="text" name="id" ng-model="user.id"><br>
    Model:<br>
    <input type="text" name="model" ng-model="user.model"><br>
    Name:<br>
    <input type="text" name="name" ng-model="user.name"><br>
    Color:<br>
    <input type="text" name="color" ng-model="user.color"><br>
    Price:<br>
    <input type="text" name="price" ng-model="user.price"><br>
    <br>
    <input type="submit" >
  </form>
```

and route

better to declare the controller on the view but you cant do them both so i chosed the view controller

```
var myapp=angular
            .module('demo',['ui.router'])
            .config(function ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider){
              $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/home');
              $stateProvider
              .state('home',{
                url:'/home',
                templateUrl:'Templates/home.html'
              })
              .state('about', {
                url:'/about',
                templateUrl:'Templates/about.html'
              })
              .state('contact',{
                url:'/contact',
                templateUrl:'Templates/contact.html'
              });

            });
```

should work that way

Comment: Please provide details and explanation of the changes to the OP's code

Comment: @Erez: changes you made I already  did that. I'm facing issue while posting   data  to the server. could you tel me how a post request should be create in angularjs

Comment: well from what i saw you didnt post anything
edited the answer. easier that way and should work